# Facebook Open Graph startForPostWithGraphPath returning "FACEBOOK_NON_JSON_RESULT" = true

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to configure an Open Graph post. I've followed the code examples on the FB developer site, and, using a test_user, a post is supposedly successfully generated. Here is my code:

```
- (void)createOGObjectForImage:(NSURL *)imageURL
{
    NSMutableDictionary<FBGraphObject> *object =
    [FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPostWithType:@"ogminigame:mini_game"
                                            title:@"Mini Game"
                                            image:@"https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png"
                                              url:imageURL
                                      description:@""];

    [FBRequestConnection startForPostWithGraphPath:@"me" 
                                       graphObject:object
                                 completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                                     if(!error) {
                                         NSLog(@"Result: %@", [result description]); 
                                         [self createOGActionWithResult:result];
                                     } else {
                                         NSLog(@"Error posting the Open Graph object to the Object API: %@", error);
                                         [self sharePhotoWithShareDialog:self openGraphAction:nil];
                                     }
                                 }];
}
```

However, nothing is appearing on the test user wall. When I step through the code, I can see that when I create the OG object, the result has the following contents:

```
"FACEBOOK_NON_JSON_RESULT" = true;
```

More specifically, it looks like this:

[image]

So when I create my Action, when I try to retrieve the objectID using: 
        NSString *objectId = [result objectForKey:@"id"];

it obviously returns nil. Am I missing a stage with the result object? I've tried searching for similar problems but there doesn't seem to be much in the way of an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems the code supplied on the Facebook developer site where you supply your custom stories is incorrect. Namely, it should look like:

```
- (void)createOGObjectForImage:(NSURL *)imageURL
{
    NSMutableDictionary<FBOpenGraphObject> *object = [FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPostWithType:@"ogminigame:mini_game"
                                                                                         title:@"Mini Game"
                                                                                         image:@"https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png"
                                                                                           url:imageURL
                                                                                   description:@""];

    [FBRequestConnection startForPostOpenGraphObject:object completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if(!error) {
            NSLog(@"Result: %@", [result description]);
            [self createOGActionWithResult:result];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error posting the Open Graph object to the Object API: %@", error);
            [self sharePhotoWithShareDialog:self openGraphAction:nil];
        }
    }];
}
```

So you cast the dictionary to an FBOpenGraphObject, rather than an FBGraphObject and call startForPostOpenGraphObject instead of startForPostWithGraphPath.

It seems to me Facebook need to be a bit more consistent with their documentation.

I still have nothing showing on the test_account page, but at least the above doesn't seem to be the cause of the issue...